# AngularJS component/scope issue in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router

I have troubles with ui-router and angularjs scope after changing state - new created scope uses old controller (or vise versa).

I use AngularJS `"angular": "1.5.8"`, and ui-router `"@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.22"`, components written in ES6 style as classes.

**Component example:**

```
import template from './my-container.html';

export const MyContainer = {
  bindings: {
  },
  template: template,
  controller: class {
    constructor($scope) {
      'ngInject';
      this.$scope = $scope;
...
```

**Route/State definition:**

```
.state('mystate', {
    url: '/mystate',
    component: 'myPage' // in myPage <my-container>
})
```

**Problem:**
On first page load everything works correctly. But when I change state and go back - any changes don't appear in template.

I mentioned that $scope.$id was changed but my controller still use previous scope object.

For debugging I added two console prints: inside onInit and myUpdateData functions.

On first screenshot we can see correct ids (init, update func, from template/dom element):

[image: On first load]

And after changing states (wrong behavior):

[image: wrong flow]

future calls updateData - it uses old (14 on scr) scope but rendered new one. So we don't see any changes in template.

Any ideas how to find out from this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Issue was in components code - I forgot to remove all references on previous controller instance and after changing state this controller left alive in memory (I'm not sure how it has been connected to new scope object but it describes solution).

When you got behavior like this - try to leave almost empty component and you will find bug.